# Xcode: How to get rid of this AdMob Log message?

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

I am using AdMob banner and interstitial in my app.
Everything is working fine but every time I launch app I get this message:

> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @"6aew1ed245y6b98b44589c19d07323411" ];

How can I get rid of this? It is pretty annoying...
I removed this part of code:

```
//request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];
```

but annoying message still come out...

here is the code I'm using:

```
//google ad banner
self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-111111111111111/111111111111111";
self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

// Enable test ads on simulators.
//request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];
[self.bannerView loadRequest:request];
//google ad banner
```

Thanks for any help
Massy

Answer (score 0):

It's a hint telling you what your device ID is in order to test AdMob. It's no warning/error in any way, to get rid of it, just copy the code into the testDevices property as suggested, and/or add GAD_SIMULATOR_ID to avoid the same message when testing in the iOS simulator

Comment: Ok, I putted the code in the property but message keep coming out... and also.. what if I want to test with real ads and not test ads?